# Django how to add taggit tags to model within template

Tags: django

I have a Django app that has a list of companies, and when the user clicks on a company they are presented with all of the details of that company.  Now I'm  trying to add a tag feature so any use can add tags to the company which they'll also be able to search on.  I've created the form and the template stuff, but now I'm stuck now on how to wire it into the View, specifically updating the Company model with the new tag(s).

**Forms.py**

```
class TagForm(forms.Form):
    tag = forms.CharField(label='Tag', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        field = 'tag'
```

**Template**

```
    <div class="add-tag-form">
        <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default btn-sm">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**View**

```
class CompanyDetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company_details.html'

    # This was my attempt to work it into the View...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = TagForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            tag = form.save(commit=False)
            tag.company = Company.objects.get(pk=pk)
            tag.save()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        context = super(CompanyDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['articles'] = Articles.objects.filter(company_id=pk).order_by('-date')
        context['transcripts'] = Transcripts.objects.filter(company_id=pk).order_by('-date')
        context['form'] = TagForm()

        # Yahoo Finance API data
        stock_symbol = self.object.stock_symbol
        data = Share(stock_symbol)
        stock_open = data.get_open()
        year_range = data.get_year_range()
        fifty_day_moving_average = data.get_50day_moving_avg()
        market_cap = data.get_market_cap()

        yahoo_finance = dict()
        yahoo_finance['stock_open'] = stock_open
        yahoo_finance['year_range'] = year_range
        yahoo_finance['fifty_day_moving_average'] = fifty_day_moving_average
        yahoo_finance['market_cap'] = market_cap
        context['yahoo_finance'] = yahoo_finance

        # Yahoo News RSS data
        yahoo_news = feedparser.parse("http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s=" + stock_symbol)
        yahoo_news = yahoo_news['entries']
        for item in yahoo_news:
            item['published'] = datetime.strptime(item['published'], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')

        context['yahoo_news'] = yahoo_news

        return context
```

**UPDATE**

The error I get "'TagForm' object has no attribute 'save'".  When I change the form from forms.Form to forms.FormModel I get the following error "Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form TagForm needs updating.".  I'm not trying to create a model, rather update it through the form.

Taggit is used in the Model

```
class Company(models.Model):
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
tags = TaggableManager()
```

Comment: And what happens when you try this? Note you mention taggit in the title, but there's no reference to it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you can do is to make a simple form for the tag, just like what you did but remove the Meta information and update the post method to just add the tag in the company.  Something like below:

```
# forms.py
class TagForm(forms.Form):
    tag = forms.CharField(label='Tag', max_length=100)

# views.py
class CompanyDetails(generic.DetailView):
    ...

    # This was my attempt to work it into the View...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        company = self.get_object()
        form = TagForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            company.tags.add(form.cleaned_data['tag'])

        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
```

Comment: That got my 99% of the way there.  I got an error on the return line stating that CompanyDetails (i.e. the view) object has not attribute 'object'.  I just changed that out with  return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/company/%s/' % self.kwargs.get('pk')) which works.  I'll try to figure out why your return line didn't work though.

Comment: It's better to redirect after a post anyway.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman thanks for the advice.  Following up though, if I add in self.object = self.get_object() then the return statement in the answer above works.

Comment: @Phillip Ahh yes, I forgot to add setting the object in the `get_context_data` . `return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(object=company))` should work.